# Navigate between pages in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement a button that when clicked change to another screen in React Js but when I try to use  it, it give me an `errror: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I don't know what else to do. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
import LinkForm from "./LinkForm";
import Links from "./Links";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Link = (props) => {
  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObject) => {
    await db.collection("links").doc().set(linkObject);
    console.log("New Task Added");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LinkForm addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.history.push("/Links");
        }}
      >
        Go Home
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

Comment: you haven't provided enough information. What does the component that is using `<Link />` look like? please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it would seem as though you have not passed `history` as a prop to your link component.

Comment: `history = useHistory(); history.push("/whatever");`  You have a function component.  Do you intend to do this as a HoC or did you want to use hooks?  You need to provide more information in how you set up your `<Router/>` if you want to pass down through props.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp your component with withRouter HOC, which will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

```
import LinkForm from "./LinkForm";
import Links from "./Links";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


const Link = (props) => {
  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObject) => {
    await db.collection("links").doc().set(linkObject);
    console.log("New Task Added");
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <LinkForm addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
        <button
            onClick={() => {
              props.history.push("/Links");
            }}
        >
          Go Home
        </button>
      </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the history by default. You can get it by using "useHistory" or "withRouter" HOC.

Example for "useHistory":

```
import LinkForm from "./LinkForm";
import Links from "./Links";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Link = (props) => {
  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObject) => {
    await db.collection("links").doc().set(linkObject);
    console.log("New Task Added");
  };
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
      <div>
        <LinkForm addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
        <button
            onClick={() => {
              history.push("/Links");
            }}
        >
          Go Home
        </button>
      </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Link);
```

But anyway it's not a good UX-wise approach.
I recommend using react router "Link" like this:

```
import LinkForm from "./LinkForm";
import Links from "./Links";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { Link as ReactRouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Link = (props) => {
  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObject) => {
    await db.collection("links").doc().set(linkObject);
    console.log("New Task Added");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LinkForm addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
      <ReactRouterLink to="/Links"> // or you mean `/${Link}`
        Go Home
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

By using react-router Link you'll have an `<a />` so the user will be able to open that link as a new tab in his/her browser too. Also better SEO!